# How show recent files?

Tags: find-file, recentf

windows 10, emacs 26.1

Suppose I open 10 files. And then restart Emacs. 
After restart I need to see what files (recent) I was open before. Is it possible to show some buffer that contain name of this 10 files?

Comment: If you use `ido-mode`, you may like `(setq ido-use-virtual-buffers t)` together with `recentf-mode`. This allows you to switch the `ido` way to a previously killed file buffer, simply re-visiting the file.

Answer (score 7):

- install `counsel` (https://oremacs.com/2015/04/09/counsel-completion/)
- Run `M-x counsel-recentf`
- Press `C-c C-o` to export the file list to a buffer

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a duplicate of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50417/9863941). Thanks to [that reference to a blog entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50422/9863941), I included

```
(require 'recentf)
(recentf-mode 1)
(setq recentf-max-menu-items 25)
(global-set-key "\C-x\ \C-r" 'recentf-open-files)
```

in my `.emacs` file.

Answer (score 1):

Customize `recentf-mode` to `on` and "Save and Apply". Afterwards you get an "Open recent" sub-menu in the "File" pull down menu.

You can visit and edit `recentf-list` by <kbd>M-x</kbd> `recentf-edit-list`.

Comment: Is it possible to show recent files by some command from minibufer?

Comment: If you use helm, see 'helm-recentf'.

Comment: I don't like package "helm"

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your followup question in comments (it really should be a separate question, or you should edit this question to make clear that you want to use the minibuffer etc.):

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then:

1. You can get `recentf`-recorded files as completion candidates during buffer-name completion (this happens by default) - see option `icicle-buffer-include-recent-files-nflag`:

   > An integer > 0 means include recent files during buffer-name completion.
   >   This means file names managed by `recentf-mode` - see (emacs) [File
   >   Conveniences](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Conveniences.html).  An integer < 0 means do not include them.
   >   When they are included, the value is the maximum number of such
   >   candidates to include.
   >
   > You can toggle this option (between + and -) using `C-x R` in the
   >   minibuffer during buffer-name completion.
2. You can use command `icicle-recent-files` to open any recently visited file - only such files are completion candidates for this command. See [Icicles - Visit Recent Files or Files for Emacs Tags](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input#VisitRecentFiles).
3. You can use command `icicle-remove-file-from-recentf-list` to remove any number of file names from the `recentf-list`, with completion.